# Fetching Next.js API Route in the app directory gives 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prisma

I am struggling with Next.js 13's `app` routing. It always gives me a 404 Not Found when I try to access, for example from Postmann.

I have this file structure:

[image]

And for example, one of my API files is:

```
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

export default async function all(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'GET') {
        return res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' });
    }

    try {
        // Get all admins using Prisma
        const admins = await prisma.admin.findMany();

        return res.status(200).json(admins);
    }
    catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to get admins' });
    }
}
```

When I send a `GET localhost:3000/api/admin/all` it always responds with a 404. Couldn't find where is the error.

I tried other file or folder namings. Calling from my own app, using the curl command, or using Postman. My other API routes give the same 404.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An API Route should be in a file called [`route.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route). Meaning `app/api/admin/all.js` should be `app/api/admin/route.js`, with the corresponding URL being `/api/admin`. Also, the functions inside  should use a specific definition:

```js
export async function GET(request) {}
```

`GET` can be replaced with `POST`, `PUT`, `PATCH`, etc. In your case, it would be:

```js
// Notice from where NextResponse is imported:
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

// Notice the funciton definiton:
export async function GET(req) {
  return NextResponse.json(
    { error: "Method not allowed" },
    {
      status: 405
    }
  );
}

// Notice the funciton definiton:
export async function POST(req) {
  try {
    // Get all admins using Prisma
    const admins = await prisma.admin.findMany();

    return NextResponse.json(admins, {
      status: 200,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return NextResponse.json(
      { error: "Failed to get admins" },
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has been very helpful.

I was following the official docs for setting up Vercel Postgres, and the example filenames and paths do not mention this "automagic" convention at all.
https://vercel.com/docs/storage/vercel-postgres/quickstart

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Youssouf's answer (which I found very helpful), if you have problems getting the content of `request.body`, use `const body = await request.json()` to get the body.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/json