# NextJS Routes not available : getting a 404

Tags: typescript, next.js

> `app/api/financial/f.ts` file :

```
 import axios from 'axios';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  const options = {
    headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '5ce3259baamsh927e932246a4b9bp13b280jsne1e7b7bc0238',
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com'
      }
}
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('https://alpha-vantage.p.rapidapi.com/query?interval=5min&function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=MSFT&datatype=json&output_size=compact',options);
    const financialData = response.data;

    res.status(200).json(financialData);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch financial data' });
  }
}
```

*what I'm putting in insomnia* : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYmlW.png)

can i get some help? I don't know what I am doing wrong and I've followed nextjs documentation

**I tried change my middleware.ts file to allow this path through without having to authenticate thinking that is were my error may lie. Here is the file : **

```
 import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const path = req.nextUrl.pathname;

  // If it's the root path or finance data route, just render it
  if (path === "/" || path === "/api/f") {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const session = await getToken({
    req,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  if (!session && path === "/protected") {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/login", req.url));
  } else if (session && (path === "/login" || path === "/register")) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL("/protected", req.url));
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

here is my next.config.js file  as well:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  typescript: {
    ignoreBuildErrors: false,
  },
  swcMinify: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
`
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetching Next.js API Route in the app directory gives 404 Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76336930/fetching-next-js-api-route-in-the-app-directory-gives-404-not-found)